# Cant print inch and feet symbols in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, symbols

Define a function print_feet_inch_short(), with parameters num_feet and num_inches, that prints using ' and " shorthand. End with a newline. Remember that print() outputs a newline by default. Ex: print_feet_inch_short(5, 8) prints:
5' 8"

My code:

```
def print_feet_inch_short(num_feet, num_inches):
    return print(num_feet , num_inches )
''' Your solution goes here '''

user_feet = int(input())
user_inches = int(input())

print_feet_inch_short(user_feet, user_inches) # Will be run with (5, 8), then (4, 11)
```

When i compile my code i get `5 8` instead of `5' 8"`
Please help me to get the inch and feet symbols in the function

Thanks in advance

Comment: `print(f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def print_feet_inch_short(num_feet, num_inches):
    print(f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"")
```

Usage:

```
>>> print_feet_inch_short(5, 8)
5' 8"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def print_feet_inch_short(num_feet, num_inches):
    #first, you cannot use both print and return in the same line
    #here you have both examples using first the print statement
    #Also, to obtain the result you need, you should use the f" string, which formats the string
    print(f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"")
    #Or you can use the .format() fucntion, and you get the same result
    print("{}' {}\"".format(num_feet,num_inches))
    #and the usung the return statement
    return f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"" 
    
user_feet = int(input())
user_inches = int(input())

#When you call the function, only the print statement gets to run
print_feet_inch_short(user_feet, user_inches)

#that's because the return statement returns the value into the function itself
#To get the return statement to appear, you use the print statement
print(print_feet_inch_short(user_feet, user_inches))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape it:

```
print("5' 8\"")
```

or with your variables:

```
print(f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"")
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
def print_feet_inch_short(num_feet, num_inches):
    print(f"{num_feet}' {num_inches}\"")
    return print_feet_inch_short

 
user_feet = int(input())
user_inches = int(input())

print_feet_inch_short(user_feet, user_inches) # Will be run with (5, 8), then (4, 11)
```